# Why doesn't this method for looping through a dictionary work

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary within a dictionary. I am trying to return the innermost dictionary ie the one with the keys name, teacher etc. To loop through I tried this.

```
courses = {
'feb2012': { 'cs101': {'name': 'Building a Search Engine',
                       'teacher': 'Dave',
                       'assistant': 'Peter C.'},
             'cs373': {'name': 'Programming a Robotic Car',
                       'teacher': 'Sebastian',
                       'assistant': 'Andy'}},
    'jan2044': { 'cs001': {'name': 'Building a Quantum Holodeck',
                       'teacher': 'Dorina'},
           'cs003': {'name': 'Programming a Robotic Robotics Teacher',
                       'teacher': 'Jasper'},
                 }
}

for e in courses:
     for y in e:
         return courses[e][y]
```

The console returns key error, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

If you were to do:

```
for e in courses:
    print e
```

You'd find that it prints `"feb2012"`, `"jan2044"` -- the values are *strings*.

So the `for y in e:` on the next line iterates through the *characters of those strings*.

You meant

```
for e in cources:
    for y in cources[e]:
        return courses[e][y]
```

However, because you *return* there, you'll only ever find one of the inner dictionaries. I wonder if that's what you need.

To get all of them, one of the ways could be to make this a *generator*, with `yield` instead of `return`:

```
def get_inner(courses):
    for e in courses:
        for y in courses[e]:  # Aside, these variable names are horrible
            yield courses[e][y]
```

And now you could loop through them with `for innerdict in get_inner(courses): ...`.

But there are many ways...

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I'm trying to get all the inner dictionaries. When should I return if I want to do that?

Comment: Also I dont understand why if I return courses[e][y] it returns only once. And also it gives a random member of the inner dictionary rather then courses[0][0]

Comment: That's what return does, it ends the function and returns with the result. Dictionaries also don't have a defined order, so what you get seems "random".

Answer (score 0):

```
for x in courses:                #Iterate through the outermost keys
    for y in courses[x]:         #Iterate through the second outer most keys
        return courses[x][y]:    #Return the innermost dictionary
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for k,v in courses.items():             #Iterates through Month/Year keys (feb2012, jan2014
    for k2,v2 in v.items():             #Iterates thought class identifer keys (cs101, cs373, cs001,cs003)
        for k3, v3 in v2.items():       #Iterates though class information (name, teacher, assistant)
            print('Semester: ' + k + '\tCourse: ' + k2 + '\tKey: ' + k3 + '\tValue: ' + v3) #Displays class information
```

Output:

```
Semester: feb2012   Course: cs101   Key: assistant  Value: Peter C.
Semester: feb2012   Course: cs101   Key: teacher    Value: Dave
Semester: feb2012   Course: cs101   Key: name   Value: Building a Search Engine
Semester: feb2012   Course: cs373   Key: assistant  Value: Andy
Semester: feb2012   Course: cs373   Key: teacher    Value: Sebastian
Semester: feb2012   Course: cs373   Key: name   Value: Programming a Robotic Car
Semester: jan2044   Course: cs001   Key: teacher    Value: Dorina
Semester: jan2044   Course: cs001   Key: name   Value: Building a Quantum Holodeck
Semester: jan2044   Course: cs003   Key: teacher    Value: Jasper
Semester: jan2044   Course: cs003   Key: name   Value: Programming a Robotic Robotics Teacher
```